# Operator does not exist: integer ~~ integer

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, maven

When sending postman get request for findbyid it gives a 500 internal server error and the following error in the terminal:
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: integer ~~ integer
Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

My User repository interface

```
public interface UserEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<UserEntity,Integer> {

    UserEntity findByName(String name);

    @Query(value = "select * from user_table where cast(id as int) like :id",nativeQuery = true)
    UserEntity findByUserById(Integer id);
```

My base Entity for creating ids:

```
public class BaseEntity {
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
}
```

My psql code:

```
id serial not null
        constraint user_table_pk
            primary key,
```

Comment: I think `findByUserById` should be called `findById` instead.

Comment: I tried using it but ended up creating this new query because findById returned optional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `like` operator is only defined for character datatypes (you cannot write a query `some_int_column like '%1%'`).

The query for `UserEntityRepository.findByUserById()` must be written as

```
@Query(value = "select * from user_table where id = :id",nativeQuery = true)
```